# Generate Multiple Sessions using Apache Shiro

Tags: java, session, swagger, shiro

I have web application which uses apache shiro for authentication & authorization, i have configured multiple authentication (DBRealm,APIRealm).
DBRealm for web application and APIRealm for Swagger Authentication.
Now there is scenario, where the session is getting swapped

- In a first tab, open web application (DBRealm, which will generate the JSessionId) (https://localhost:8080/ecommerce/fin.html)
- Now in the second tab, i am opening the Swagger application (APIRealm, which will generate the different JSessionId after validating the api key).(https://localhost:8080/ecommerce/swagger/index.html)

Now if i go back to first tab, the session generated from swagger is passed along with the web application and vice versa. Which is causing lot of issues in my application.

- How to generate separate session for both web & swagger application?
- or how to resolve the session swapping issue in apache shiro in same domain?

PS:: Shiro.ini file configuration

```
#realm configuration
apiRealm=com.example.realm.ComAPIRealm
pac4jRealm=com.example.realm.ComPac4jRealm
dbRealm=com.example.realm.ComJdbcRealm
ldapRealm=com.example.realm.ComLdapRealm
securityManager.realms=$dbRealm,$ldapRealm,$pac4jRealm,$apiRealm

authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy

authcBasic = com.example.ecommerce.ComBasicFilter

# session ans session related properties configuration
sessionManager=org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager=$sessionManager
#securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 1800000
sessionValidationScheduler = org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.ExecutorServiceSessionValidationScheduler
sessionValidationScheduler.interval = 300000
sessionValidationScheduler.sessionManager = $sessionManager
sessionManager.sessionValidationSchedulerEnabled=true
sessionManager.deleteInvalidSessions=true
sessionManager.sessionValidationScheduler = $sessionValidationScheduler
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.name=JSESSIONID_ECOM
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager

[urls]
/rest/api/**=authcBasic
```

- dbRealm extends jdbcRealm
- ApiRealm extends jdbcRealm
- pac4jRealm extends io.buji.pac4j.realm.Pac4jRealm
- ldapRealm extends DefaultLdapRealm

Comment: How is Shiro configured?  StackOverflow has a great resource on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: configured using shiro.ini and $authcStrategy is FirstSuccessfulStrategy , #realm configuration --securityManager.realms=$dbRealm,$ldapRealm,$pac4jRealm,$apiRealm &securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.name=JSESSIONID_ECOM,sessionManager=org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager

Comment: What are your dependencies? It doesn't look like Shiro is protected the paths you mentioned, I only see `/rest/api/**` in your config, and that one uses BASIC Auth.  If using Basic Authentication through a browser the browser would cache the credentials (separate from your cookies).  I'd suggest creating a minimal example project and sticking it on GitHub (or similar), and adding that do your post